# MVC 4 - Accessing url typed in web browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url, browser

In my MVC 4 application, I would like to retrieve the exact URL used by the browser to navigate to my page. Is there any way to do this? Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl
```